# SharePoint File Upload Column

Tags: sharepoint

I have a user that has developed a survey. As part of the survey, they want to provide four questions/columns to where the respondent can upload files.

1. Is anyone aware of a file upload column type?
2. Is there a programmatic way to achieve this utilizing document libraries? The fields show up on the form but the data is stored on a document library with a Lookup column from the survey?

The goals are to receive documents from the user in the process and make it as seamless as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: woops misunderstood...

Short answer, using a Survey List type you are unable to upload files. You would have to create a custom list to do this type of thing, but cannot do so otherwise.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8806/attaching-an-item-to-survey-list